# change classname dynamically when append div

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's working fine for a single row. but when I am appending extra rows that time it shows all the hidden div and when I change the route to value all destination div are changing. but I need to change each row accordingly. here is my code sample.

```js
//add div by onclick event from button
function add() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  div.innerHTML = `
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>DTMF</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 route">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Route to</label>
                <select class="form-control" onchange="change(this)" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="department">department</option>
                  <option value="employee">employee</option>
                  <option value="area">area</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 department">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Destination</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">dep-1</option>
                  <option value="2">dep-2</option>
                  <option value="3">dep-3</option>
                  <option value="4">dep-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 employee">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">emp-1</option>
                  <option value="2">emp-2</option>
                  <option value="3">emp-3</option>
                  <option value="4">emp-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 area">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Area</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">area-1</option>
                  <option value="2">area-2</option>
                  <option value="3">area-3</option>
                  <option value="4">area-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>`;
  document.getElementById("appenhere").appendChild(div);
}
//hide div by css class
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".department").hide();
  $(".employee").hide();
  $(".area").hide();
});
//show div by onchange event
function change(select) {
  //   console.log(select.value);
  var parent = $(select).siblings().siblings();
  console.log(parent);
  if (select.value == "department") {
    $(".department").show();
    $(".employee").hide();
    $(".area").hide();
  } else if (select.value == "employee") {
    $(".department").hide();
    $(".employee").show();
    $(".area").hide();
  } else if (select.value == "area") {
    $(".department").hide();
    $(".employee").hide();
    $(".area").show();
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>test page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>DTMF</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 route">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Route to</label>
          <select class="form-control" onchange="change(this)" name="" id="">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="department">department</option>
            <option value="employee">employee</option>
            <option value="area">area</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 department">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Destination</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">dep-1</option>
            <option value="2">dep-2</option>
            <option value="3">dep-3</option>
            <option value="4">dep-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 employee">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Employee</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">emp-1</option>
            <option value="2">emp-2</option>
            <option value="3">emp-3</option>
            <option value="4">emp-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 area">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Area</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">area-1</option>
            <option value="2">area-2</option>
            <option value="3">area-3</option>
            <option value="4">area-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="appenhere"></div>
    <button onclick="add()">Add more</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your words here are very difficult to understand. you are going to have to try to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: You're already using that why are you using `onclick` attribute? Do on click event using jquery in your js file.

Answer (score 0):

Get the containing row with `$(select).closest(".row")`. Then you can change just the elements in the same row.

Use CSS to initially hide the dependent menus, instead of calling `.hide()` in `$(document).ready()`, so it will apply to the elements that are added dynamically.

```js
//add div by onclick event from button
function add() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");

  div.innerHTML = `
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>DTMF</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 route">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Route to</label>
                <select class="form-control" onchange="change(this)" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <option value="department">department</option>
                  <option value="employee">employee</option>
                  <option value="area">area</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 department">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Destination</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">dep-1</option>
                  <option value="2">dep-2</option>
                  <option value="3">dep-3</option>
                  <option value="4">dep-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 employee">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">emp-1</option>
                  <option value="2">emp-2</option>
                  <option value="3">emp-3</option>
                  <option value="4">emp-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4 area">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Area</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="1">area-1</option>
                  <option value="2">area-2</option>
                  <option value="3">area-3</option>
                  <option value="4">area-4</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>`;
  document.getElementById("appenhere").appendChild(div);
}
//show div by onchange event
function change(select) {
  //   console.log(select.value);
  var parent = $(select).closest(".row");
  console.log(parent);
  if (select.value == "department") {
    parent.find(".department").show();
    parent.find(".employee").hide();
    parent.find(".area").hide();
  } else if (select.value == "employee") {
    parent.find(".department").hide();
    parent.find(".employee").show();
    parent.find(".area").hide();
  } else if (select.value == "area") {
    parent.find(".department").hide();
    parent.find(".employee").hide();
    parent.find(".area").show();
  }
}
```

```css
.department,
.employee,
.area {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>test page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>DTMF</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 route">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Route to</label>
          <select class="form-control" onchange="change(this)" name="" id="">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="department">department</option>
            <option value="employee">employee</option>
            <option value="area">area</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 department">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Destination</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">dep-1</option>
            <option value="2">dep-2</option>
            <option value="3">dep-3</option>
            <option value="4">dep-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 employee">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Employee</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">emp-1</option>
            <option value="2">emp-2</option>
            <option value="3">emp-3</option>
            <option value="4">emp-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 area">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Area</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
            <option value="1">area-1</option>
            <option value="2">area-2</option>
            <option value="3">area-3</option>
            <option value="4">area-4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="appenhere"></div>
    <button onclick="add()">Add more</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. its working now but all the hidden divs are showing. how can I hide them?

Comment: Use CSS instead of those calls to `.hide()` in the `$(document.ready` function. Because they only hide the initial divs, not the ones that are added dynamically.

Comment: $(".department").css("display", "none");
i used this but not working :(

Comment: I meant CSS in the `<style>` tag, not JavaScript. I've updated the answer.